# GVIM is taking time to start when invoked across different machines?

Tags: user-interface, vim, vi

As part of my work I will have multiple terminals with logins to various machines in network. I observed that GVIM gui is taking time to start when invoked from machine different than the previous gvim invoke.

If first I invoked gvim on machine1 and next on machine2, the second gvim invoke is taking time to open gvim GUI. Now if I again invoke gvim on machine2 I am not seeing any issue and it opens fast.

I used `gvim --startuptime gvim.log` and found that invoking GUI is taking more time.

```
077.501  000.210  000.210: sourcing /cpd/misc/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
079.475  000.376  000.376: sourcing /cpd/misc/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
079.541  020.108: loading plugins
079.547  000.006: inits 3
097.793  001.193  001.193: sourcing $VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim
9586.733  9505.993: starting GUI
9587.988  001.255: reading viminfo
9589.083  001.095: GUI delay
9591.074  001.991: register server name
9591.076  000.002: setting raw mode
9591.077  000.001: start termcap
9591.132  000.055: clearing screen
9591.193  000.061: opening buffers
9591.278  000.085: BufEnter autocommands
9591.283  000.005: editing files in windows
9592.790  001.507: VimEnter autocommands
9592.796  000.006: before starting main loop
9641.761  048.965: first screen update
9641.766  000.005: --- VIM STARTED ---
```

I am using vim 7.4

Could any one please tell me how can I fix this issue?

PS: I am not seeing this issue in emacs.

Edit: These are the option with which my gvim is compiled.

+arabic +autocmd +balloon_eval +browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent +clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments
 +cryptv +cscope +cursorshape +dialog_con_gui +diff +digraphs +dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi +file_in_path +find_in_path
+folding -footer +fork() +gettext -hangul_input +iconv +insert_expand +jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap +menu
 +mksession +modify_fname +mouse +mouseshape +mouse_dec +mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm +mouse_netterm +mouse_xterm +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme
-netbeans_intg -osfiletype +path_extra +perl +postscript +printer +profile +python +quickfix +reltime +rightleft -ruby +scrollbind +signs +smartindent
-sniff +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary +tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title +toolbar
+user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo +vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup +X11 -xfontset +xim

Comment: Please explain how you "invoke GVim on machineX".

Comment: I am invoking "gvim temp" command my terminal. FYI I have also added options with which gvim is compiled.

Comment: I am wondering if `X11-clientserver` feature is somehow causing this delay. Can you start both Vim instances with an empty servername and see if the problem goes away? I think specifying `--servername ""` should do the trick.